# How can I rewrite a simple where on a foreign key using the Criteria API

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

Here's my HQL

```
select distinct p from PayerCriteria p where p.determinationRequest.id = :determinationRequestId
```

I think the only important unknown here is that `determinationRequest.id` is a `Long`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to necessarily create the Join object as mentioned by @uaiHebert. You can create the where predicate of your hql query using:

```
Predicate wherePredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("determinationRequest").get("id"), determinationRequestId)
```

I have added comments into the code below that explain what the individual lines do.

```
CriteriaQuery<PayerCriteria> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(PayerCriteria.class);

//This creates the from clause of the hql query
Root<PayerCriteria> root = criteriaQuery.from(PayerCriteria.class);

//The Where clause(on FK property) can be created like so
Predicate wherePredicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("determinationRequest").get("id"), determinationRequestId);

//This creates the final query object and adds the Distinct constraint
criteriaQuery.select(root).where(wherePredicate).distinct(true);

Query<PayerCriteria> query = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

List<PayerCriteria> payerCriteriaList = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a CriteriaAPI you would need to do:

```
    final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<PayerCriteria> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(PayerCriteria.class);
    final Root<PayerCriteria> root = criteriaQuery.from(PayerCriteria.class);
    criteriaQuery.select(root);

    final Join join = root.join("determinationRequest");

    final Predicate predicate = criteriaBuilder.equal(join.get("id"), 1);
    criteriaQuery.where(predicate);

    final TypedQuery<PayerCriteria> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

    System.out.println("------------>" + query.getResultList());
```

There is a framework that makes that burden easier named EasyCriteria (http://easycriteria.uaihebert.com). The criteria above would be like:

```
    EasyCriteria<RegularEntityOne> easyCriteria = EasyCriteriaFactory.createQueryCriteria(entityManager, RegularEntityOne.class);
    easyCriteria.innerJoin("regularEntityTwo");
    easyCriteria.andEquals("regularEntityTwo.id", 1);

    System.out.println("------------>" + easyCriteria.getResultList());
```